# Android BitmapFactory vs. BufferedInputStream

Tags: android, bitmapfactory, bufferedinputstream

Does `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream)` already read in substantial chunks or should one be sure to pass a `BufferedInputStream` rather than a raw `InputStream` to it?

I ask as if `BitmapFactory` isn't doing IO in sizable blocks already, then one should clearly apply buffering to the input stream before passing it.  If, however, it is already working in large blocks then applying a buffering is essentially just adding an unnecessary set of `memcpy()` operations.

It would be really nice if those writing APIs taking `InputStream` or `OutputStream` arguments were clear on such things in the Javadoc.

Currently, I am applying buffering unless `InputStream` is an instance of `AssetManager.AssetInputStream`, as I note special handling of that case under `decodeStream()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementation, there are two methods that decodeStream might call.

- nativeDecodeAsset(), which doesnt seem to show an implementation when I look through the class
- decodeStreamInternal(), which reads `16 * 1024` bytes at once judging by the size of `DECODE_BUFFER_SIZE`

  (id post the code but the formatting seems to be broken right now)

So I would assume that using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` is a safe choice